# capturando palabras con keyup

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de obtener mediante el metodo key up lo que se escriba en el imput, pero al hacer la aplicación me entrega letras, lo que es un problema porque necesito crear un elemento button para una palabra completa no para cada letra.

Como podría hacer para capturar palabras completas y no letras independientes.

Gracias por la ayuda

```js
var numbers = document.getElementById("numeros");
numbers.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    console.log(e.key)
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numeros">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que cometes es que en el parámetro `e` de la funcion que disparas cada vez que se oprime una letra, solamente estas obteniendo el `e.key` que es la letra que se presiono

Lo que deberías hacer es que cada vez que hay un evento `keyup` debes obtener el valor del input para imprimirlo completo

Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
$("#text").on('keyup', ()=>{
    var valor = $("#text").val()//aqui se obtiene el valor del input cada vez que se presiona un tecla
    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = valor
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text">
<div></div>
```

en javascript puro seria lo siguiente:

```
var numbers = document.getElementById("numeros");
   numbers.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
     var valor = numbers.value;
     console.log(valor)
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <input id="campoPalabra" type="text" />
    
    <script>
     var n = document.getElementById("campoPalabra");
     n.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      palabra = document.getElementById("campoPalabra").value;
      console.log(palabra);
     });
    </script>
```